# Can't add Android under Eclipse-plugin on Windows 7 - Not visible

Tags: android, windows-7, eclipse-plugin

I've tried to search for similar problems, but can't seem to find it.

I run:

- Windows 7
- Java SE Developement Kit x64
- Eclipse Helios (downloaded here from Eclipses homepage --> Downloads --> Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers --> 64 Bit)
- "Android SDK Windows"

I've been following the guide from the Android Developers homepage.

I can launch Eclipse just fine. Under Help --> Install New Software ... 
Here, I give it a name myself (Android Plugin Test), and under location, I've typed "http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse", as said in the link.
Then it find Developement Kit, and I install it and all that & restart Eclipse.

The following are now installed:
- Android DDMS
- Android Development Tools
- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

So everything seems fine.
BUT ..
When I go to Window --> Preferences, "Android" is missing.
I have no problems seeing General, Ant, Data Management etc.

So my question is, what's the problem ?

As said, I downloaded Android SDK, but when I try to run the setup, I get this error, about missing Java:

http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/600/javaproblem.jpg

And that's where I'm lost.
Because, under installed programs, it says:
- Java(TM) SE Developement Kit 6 Update 21 (64-bit)

And yes, I have restarted after installing Java.

For some odd reason, it's not possible for to run the SDK setup with any compatibility. It's greyed out
(Yes, I'm admin, and I don't have any problems on other programs)

I checked the Requirements for Android SDK, and it says Windows XP & Vista, but not 7 .. But as far as I know, other people got it to work.

So .. What am I doing wrong ?
Do you have any solutions ?

If I need to download other Java versions (or anything else), please provide links.

Comment: There is a difference between being installed and being in your path.  Make sure that if you open a command prompt and type "java" you get something other than a "not found" -- i.e. it should print the usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care of three things...I too faced similar problems so can tell you how to go about it:
1) Download Eclipse -> 32 bit version...since your SDk is 32 bit...make sure ur JDK is 32 bit...
2) After downloading 32 bit version install Android ADT first......
3)Then go to Preference-> Android -> Give the SDk path here......n then download the platforms and samples....

Feel free to ask if your still unable to get it sorted coz i faced similar problems....

Comment: Rohan, could you please provide a link, because I have a hard time finding the right Java software to download ?
Thanks in advance.
And should I uninstall Java JDK x64 ?

Comment: Alright, it figured it out.
After some test downloads & a few restarts, I'm FINALLY installing some SDK packages.
So I suppose the problem is solved so far !

Thanks a lot for fast answers !!

Comment: JDK 32 bit should be installed on your PC ....You can download it from Sun site...

Comment: Yeah I realized. I got the SDK to work now, and it can launch Android 2.2 (I'ved only tested that), so that's perfect now. I've got JDK 32 bit & Eclipse 32 bit to work as well. But the "Android" still doesn't show up, under Window --> Preferences. Any ideas ? Under Help --> Install new software .. I've just entered a name I came up with myself, and Location is: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ So yeah .. Any ideas what might be wrong ?

I've tried to change the Enviroment Variables, as Totramon, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Android is displayed only after ADT is installed....GO to help-> Install new software -> Then give the ADT path...It will install new software...After this step Android will be displayed above Preferences ....

Comment: I found my mistake. I downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers", and not "Eclipse Classic 3.6.0". I downloaded the last mentioned, and it works perfectly now.
Thanks alot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you need to add your Java's /bin path to your path environment variable by hand. Open your Computer by right-clicking, go to Advanced system settings, then Environment Variables and add the full path to the Path variable. For example, I added `;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin` to the existing string.